# Matching Data in List and Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, document-library

I have a List with several columns, including a 'CQUniqueID' column.

I have a Library that also has a 'CQUniqueID' column.

The CQUniqueID is created with a condition in a PowerApps form. That form has an attachment control and a submit button. When the submit button is clicked a Path condition updates the List and a Flow upload the attachment to the Library.

I need to be able to get the content of the 'CQUniqueID' field in the List Patch and also Patch (or Update) that content to the 'CQUniqueID' field in the Library associated with the newly uploaded document.

In the end the Library and List 'CQUniqueID' columns should have the same 'CQUniqueID' content for each List line item and corresponding Library document.

How do I best achieve this task?`

Answer (score 0):

As I am not sure about the type of "CQUniqueID", just assume it to be a number from its name.

The most straightforward way will be like adding a new flow. Triggered when item is created/modified in the list. As you mention there is some kind of relationship between the item and file in library. If you can get the file ID from the list item, just use the `Update File Properties` action to update the column directly. Or you may need to use the `Get Files` action to filter with the criteria you have based on the relationship. With it, get the correct file you need, then update the property.